MacOS spellcheck is British but the keyboard is US English
I am running Ventura 13.6.6, with Ukrainian and US English keyboards set up. And yet, spellcheck keeps pushing British English spelling. Organize is corrected to Organise & flavor is corrected to Flavour. This happens here in Safari as well as in emails & Pages, etc. So it seems to be an OS setting. But all I can find is the keyboard, which is already US English. Any thoughts on a possible other cause? Really frustrating when doing a lot of writing is on my agenda at the moment, and not for a GB audience.

Keyboard setting reflects the physical keyboard - not language. What is in your System Settings > Language & Region? Screenshot might help.

@gilby When I go there I see Preferred Languages, English & Ukrainian. Greyed out and the same ones set up in my Keyboard settings. And no customisations for a specific application.

When you say English, is that English (US)? AFAIK, English is this context always has a country qualifier.

Just realised, you need to check Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources Edit... > Spelling. Mine is "Automatic by Language" and does Australian English spelling, but you might need to set that to US English.

Apple and most other apps do use the system settings for spelling.  The big exception being Microsoft Office which has its own spelling settings.
